# IIS URL rewrite module- redirect rule not working

Tags: url, iis

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect CM" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^HVProduct$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.CMMDesign.com/Management/Contact" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

I wanted to redirect users to another page
when ever they try to access "www.CMMDesign.com/HVProduct" redirect to
"http://www.CMMDesign.com/Management/Contact"

I tried with exact match and wild card also not working. Any ideas?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 0):

First you must install the URL rewrite module, if not installed, please follow the steps below to install:

1):Visit http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite ;

2):At the bottom of the page you can download the installer without using Web Platform.

3):Run the MSI installer to add the URL Rewrite Module to your server.

[image]

Then modify your URL Rewrite rules as follows:

```
 <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Test" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)(HVProduct)" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.CMMDesign.com/Management/Contact" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
  </rewrite>
```